# Graph truncation in PDF document generated by RMD

Tags: ggplot2, pdf, r-markdown

I am exporting around 10 graphs generated using ggplot2 from r markdown to PDF. First page of my pdf comes out to be blank and second page has 2 graphs, second graph is only partially visible and cuts off as the page ends. Third page shows 3rd graph. This way I am able to see 1st graph on 2nd page, 2nd graph (only half as it get's cropped) on 2nd page itself, 3rd graph onwards on next pages without getting cropped. I am including ```{r echo=FALSE, fig.margin=TRUE, fig.pos='H',fig.width = 20,fig.height = 14, results='asis', comment=FALSE, warning= FALSE, message=FALSE}''' at the start of my chunk. Please help to resolve the issue.

I even tried to include   cat("\n\n\pagebreak\n") in my for loop which finally prints the plots-
for(p in plotv) {
print(p)
cat("\n\n\pagebreak\n")
}